# What-If and Sensitivity Analysis and with Power BI when the value is set manually

Tags: powerbi

I would really appreciate your help with the following issue:
I have a PBI report in which I have a list of business units, and for each unit there is a ratio between two KPIs. What I'm supposed to do is to add functionality that allows us to feed (manually) the value which will be added to the numerator and the other value which will be added to the denominator, and then to "simulate" the value of the "new ratio" when these 2 values are given (addition to numerator and addition to denominator)
I'm not sure what is the implementation in PBI, and in particular - how can I make this manually - feeding work  ( like if it was just an excel worksheet where you can enter a value and the entire worksheet will be refreshed in accordance to it). THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR ALL HELPERS!

Comment: Have you tried [what-if parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if)?

Comment: I haven't . Great idea, thank you Alexis! I'll try and  tell if it worked:)